# I am looping axios in a loop, but I am not getting response related to the request, Response is getting mixed up

Tags: reactjs

```
for (let index = 0; index < kpiIdArr.length; index++) {

  const executeDashboardMutation = {
    query: `query {
            executeDashboard(dashboardId:"${windowId}",kpiId:"${element.kpi_id}",dashboardParam:"${jsonToSend}"){data, messageCode, title, message}
        }`,
  }

  const execDashRes = Axios.post(
    GENERICURL,
    executeDashboardMutation, 
    {headers: headers},
    {async: true},
    {crossDomain: true},
  ).then((execDashRes) => {
    console.log("====execDashRes======", execDashRes)
  })

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by mixed up?  If you mean the console logs are out of order, you need to do this with async/await in your loop so that you aren't firing all the requests at the same time, which is why it logs as whichever completes first instead of order fired.

Comment: the for loop is not waiting for your data to be returned, it will just continue looping until it reaches the end. Not caring about your request

Comment: Mixed up in the sense, I am not getting reponse for the request that I send.

If I use async await, I will have to wait till the first response is completed.
Means till the response of the first request come I won't be able to get another response

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in an async function then await the response:

```
const fetchSomeData = async () => {
 for (let index = 0; index < kpiIdArr.length; index++) {

  const executeDashboardMutation = {
    query: `query {
            executeDashboard(dashboardId:"${windowId}",kpiId:"${element.kpi_id}",dashboardParam:"${jsonToSend}"){data, messageCode, title, message}
        }`,
  }

  await const execDashRes = Axios.post(
    GENERICURL,
    executeDashboardMutation, 
    {headers: headers},
    {async: true},
    {crossDomain: true},
  )

  console.log(execDashRes)

}
}
```